# Changing the domain name displayed in emails

Tags: firebase-authentication

We've created an `firebase-authentication` app for domain `foo.bar.com`. Afterwards we've changed that `foo.bar.com` is actually `doo.bar.com`. How can I change the domain `firebase-authentication` uses so that the links in the emails are correct?

For reference I want to change the link that appears here:

[image]

---

I cannot change the content of the email and I cannot find a place where I can change the domain globally. I can see action URL, but I don't think that I should be changing that:

[image]

Comment: Customizing the action URL will customize the landing page for out of band email operations like email verification, password reset, etc.

Comment: @bojeil is there no global place where I can change this? Seems silly to update it for 3 emails when domain name changes.

Comment: Changing it for one will change it for all in the Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @bojeil comment, the way to achieve what I want is to use `action URL`. This will change it in all three default email templates.

As I've not setup this project, I'd assume there should be one place where you can specify this setting and define footer (or content of those templates altogether)

Answer (score 5):

I think you are just missing something thats hidden out of view:
[image]

When you click on the edit/pencil button next to the "From" address, in any of the templates, you will find the option you are looking for:

[image]
[image]

Note that you add a CUSTOM domain, which you have to own to add the verification codes to the DNS records.

In your screenshots you use foo-bar.firebaseapp.com, so a subdomain that Firebase is providing for you, generated from the project's name.

I don't think you can change this to use a different firebaseapp.com subdomain other than by creating a new Firebase project with the doo-bar name.

Comment: Thank you for the step by step response. I don't have access to the DNS settings to verify the domain ownership, but I think that this is a setting to display the domain that is displayed in the email (while link used might point to different place). The comment made by @bojeil achieves what I wanted, but it is a terrible UX, as you'd not think to change it there